# No detecta librería al cambiar el contenido de la página

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Buen Día, Tengo un problema al cambiar de contenido de una página con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

Especifico como esta mi proyecto tengo 2 páginas `layout` uno para el `login` y otro para el `index` después del haber iniciado sesión. También esta una vista `_viewStart.cshtml` que lo único que contiene es `@{Layout="~/Views/Shared/_LayoutIndex.cshtml"}`

Explico mi problema:

1. Tengo mi página `_Layout.cshtml` donde cargo todos mis `scripts`

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="es">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
       <title>Calendario | KrestonZac</title>
       <link rel="icon" href="~/img/kreston/icono_kreston1.ico" />

       <!-- Bootstrap -->
       <link href="~/css/iconos/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="~/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="~/css/fullCalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="~/css/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="~/css/formValidation/formValidation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="~/css/Notificaciones/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <!--Estilos de la plantilla-->
       <link href="~/css/flat-ui-pro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="~/css/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="~/css/misEstilos/miEstilo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
       <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
       <!--[if lt IE 9]>
         <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
       <![endif]-->

       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="~/js/select2/select2.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/i18n/es.js"></script>
       <script src="~/js/flat-ui-pro.js"></script>
       <script src="~/js/timePicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
       <script src="~/js/datePicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>@*rango de fechas para el evento*@
       <script src="~/js/datePair/datepair.js"></script>@*rango de fechas para el evento*@
       <script src="~/js/datePair/jquery.datepair.js"></script>@*rango de fechas para el evento*@
       <script src="~/js/fullCalendar/lib/moment.min.js"></script>@*base del calendario*@
       <script src="~/js/fullCalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>@*funciones del calendario*@
       <script src="~/js/fullCalendar/lang/es.js"></script>@*lenguaje del calendario*@
       <script src="~/js/dataTables/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
       <script src="~/js/formValidation/formValidation.js"></script>@*validaciones de todos los formularios*@
       <script src="~/js/formValidation/framework/bootstrap.js"></script>@*validaciones de todos los formularios*@
       <script src="~/js/formValidation/language/es_ES.js"></script>@*validaciones de todos los formularios*@
       <script src="~/js/Notificaciones/toastr.js"></script>@*notificaciones en la pagina*@
       <script src="~/js/Calendario/FuncionesCalendario.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body >
       @RenderBody()
       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   </body >
   </html>
   ```
2. Donde `@RenderBody()` llama a mi `index`, ("*en el cual tengo la referencia de que uso un `layout`*"), en el cual tengo un `div` para cargar fragmentos de páginas que tengo creadas:

   ```
   <div class="col-sm-9">
       <div class="contenido">
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

   - Dentro de ese contenido cargo por `JQuery` las vistas con `.load()`
3. Esto corresponde a lo que cargo principalmente:

   ```
   <div class="panel panel-success">
   <div class="panel-heading">
       <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
           <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Mensajes">
               <input type="radio" name="options" id="Mensajes">
               <span class="fui-bubble">&nbsp;</span>Mensajes
           </label>
           <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Citas">
               <input type="radio" name="options" id="Citas">
               <span class="fui-calendar">&nbsp;</span>Citas
           </label>
           <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Tareas">
               <input type="radio" name="options" id="Tareas">
               <span class="fa fa-clock-o">&nbsp;</span>Tareas
           </label>
       </div>
       <div class="pull-right" id="Close"><button class="btn btn-link btn-xs" title="Cancelar"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <form class="form-horizontal" id="Historial">
           <input name="Tipo" type="hidden" id="TipoH" />
           <div class="row form-group" style="display:none;" id="Descripcion">
               <input type="text" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Titulo" class="form-control" style="border-color: transparent; min-height: 24px;" required />
           </div>
           <hr style="margin: 5px; border-top: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.40);display:none;" id="Separador" />
           <div class="row form-group" id="Notas_iniciales">
               <textarea id="AddH" name="Notas_Inicio" placeholder="Agregar Mensaje" class="form-control" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; min-height: 30px;"></textarea>
           </div>
           <div class="row form-group" id="fechas" style="margin-top: 10px; display:none;">
               <div class="col-sm-1">
                   <label class="control-label">De:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                       <div class="row col-md-7">
                           <div class="input-group">
                               <input name="Fecha_Inicio" type="text" class="date start form-control" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" style="border-right: 0;" />
                               <span class="input-group-addon fui-calendar" style="background: transparent; color: #bdc3c7;"></span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <div class="input-group">
                               <input name="Hora_Inicio" type="text" class="time start form-control" placeholder="Hora Inicio" style="border-right: 0;" />
                               <span class="input-group-addon fui-time" style="background: transparent; color: #bdc3c7;"></span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="row col-md-1" style="text-align:center;">
                       <label class="control-label">A:</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <div class="input-group">
                               <input name="Hora_Fin" type="text" class="time end form-control" placeholder="Hora Fin" style="border-right: 0;" />
                               <span class="input-group-addon fui-time" style="background: transparent; color: #bdc3c7;"></span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="row col-md-7">
                           <div class="input-group">
                               <input name="Fecha_Fin" type="text" class="date end form-control" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" style="border-right: 0;" />
                               <span class="input-group-addon fui-calendar" style="background: transparent; color: #bdc3c7;"></span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id="Limite">
               <div class="col-sm-1">
                   Fecha Limite:
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-11">
                   <div class="input-group">
                       <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <button class="btn" type="button"><span class="fui-calendar"></span></button>
                       </span>
                       <input name="Fecha_Limite" type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-01" />
                       <input name="Fecha_Inicio" type="hidden" class="form-control" value="today" id="fechainicio" />
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id="Cliente">
               <div class="col-sm-1">
                   <label class="control-label">Cliente:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-11">
                   <select name="id_Cliente" class="form-control multiselect" id="id_clienteH">
                       <option></option>
                   </select>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id="Lugar">
               <div class="col-sm-1">
                   <label class="control-label">Lugar:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-11">
                   <select name="Lugar" class="form-control" id="LugarCli" multiple></select>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id="Prioridad">
               <div class="col-sm-1">
                   <label class="control-label">Prioridad</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-11">
                   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                       <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active">
                           <input type="radio" name="Prioridad" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked value="0">
                           Ninguna
                       </label>
                       <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                           <input type="radio" name="Prioridad" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="1">
                       Baja
                       </label>
                       <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                           <input type="radio" name="Prioridad" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="2">
                           Media
                       </label>
                       <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                           <input type="radio" name="Prioridad" id="option4" autocomplete="off" value="3">
                           Alta
                       </label>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id="UserDestino">
               <div class="col-sm-1">
                   <label class="control-label">Para:</label>
                   <label class="control-label" style="display:none;">Asiste:</label>
                   <label class="control-label" style="display:none;">Participa:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-9">
                   <input name="usersID" type="hidden" id="userIDH" />
                   <select class="form-control multiselect" id="userIDselect" multiple>
                   </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Publicar</button>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="display:none;" onclick="return validarForm();">Realizar</button>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                   <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm" style="color: black;"><span class="fui-clip"></span></button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   /*inicializacion y Configuracion de las Fechas*/
   $('#fechas .time').timepicker({
       'showDuration': true,
       'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
       'step': 15,
       'forceRoundTime': true
   });
   $('#fechas .date, #limite input').datepicker({
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
       autoclose: true,
       language: "es",
       weekStart: 0,
       startDate: (new Date())//este solo se usara si el administrador permite agregar fechas pasadas
   });    
   // inicializamos datepair
   var defaultDeltaExampleEl = document.getElementById('fechas');
   var defaultDeltaDatepair = new Datepair(defaultDeltaExampleEl, {
       'defaultDateDelta': 1,      // days
       'defaultTimeDelta': 3600000 // milliseconds
   });
   });
   </script>
   ```

Cuando inicia por primera vez la página funciona normal pero cuando cambio el contenido del `div` por otro segmento de código y vuelvo a cargar el punto 3 en consola me dice:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function

**NOTA:

Hago uso de `SignalR 2.2.0` para la notificación de todos los clientes conectados.

Antes de implementar [signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr) funcionaba perfecto.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de modificar el contenido de la vista `_viewStart.cshtml` salían mayores errores, como lo eran no cargar las librerías que se necesitaban para las otras vistas parciales cuando únicamente el fallo era en el `timepicker`.

La solución fue eliminar la vista `_viewStart.cshtml` y funciono todo sin problemas, el único movimiento que hice para que funcionara correctamente [signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr) fue mover toda la estructura de los `script` al `index`.

**NOTA: Las referencias de los `layouts` se encuentran en el `index` y `login`**

Answer (score 0):

por lo que puedo ver en tu código tienes la siguiente ruta

```
<script src="~/js/timePicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
```

Donde supongo es un llamado relativo de la librería que funciona bien cuando estas en la raíz de proyecto, pero cuando pasas de / a /algunaRuta/ en esta no existe la librería por eso es el error, por lo cual re recomiendo tener un path absoluto para cargar esas librerías.

Comment: No es eso debido a que mi contenido solo modifica el `div` del punto 2, por lo tanto no es cuestión de la ruta